# Unable to launch spoon from intellij

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to launch PDI spoon from intellij(running in windows).
/lib/*.jar and /libswt/win64/* have been added.
PDI version - pdi-ce-6.1.0.1-196.
But it is crashing mid way with the following error:

```
ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.ui.xul.XulException: Can not locate Xul document [ui/spoon.xul]
2016/07/28 11:33:07 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulLoader.findDocument(AbstractXulLoader.java:520)
2016/07/28 11:33:07 - General -     at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulLoader.loadXul(AbstractXulLoader.java:238)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's because spoon ui needs config files.Download [pentaho-kettle](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle) source  then copy assembly/package-res/ui to your root dir.It will work.